# can i write a function or just create a variable inside jsx element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What my aim is to create a variable to store a result of `if` condition, which will be used to render html things.

```
<TableBody>
  {() => { //---> Not Getting into this function
    const source =                              
      selectedPerformance.length > 0
      ? selectedPerformance
      : performance;
    source.map((emp) => {
      const isItemSelected = isSelected(emp.id);
      return (
        <TableRow hover key={emp._id}>
          <TableCell>{emp.id}</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      )
    }
</TableBody>
```

But when I try this I didn't get type errors. I thought it will work but it was not getting into the function.

I know that I can write it in different way, like without creating that function and variable inside the jsx just by using conditional rendering, but for that i have to repeat the same code again and again. I don't want to do that.

Is there any better way?

Comment: Your `fat arrow function` as whereas your `map function` seem to luck matching closing `'}'` and `')'` respectively.

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your `fat arrow functions` as whereas your `map function` seem to luck matching closing `'}'` and `')'` respectively.

After fixing that, you could make your outmost `fat arrow` to become an IIFE(Immediately Invoked Function Expression).

```
(function () {
    statements
})();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE

```
<TableBody>
    {
        (() => {
            const source =
                selectedPerformance.length > 0
                    ? selectedPerformance
                    : performance;
            source.map(
                (emp) => {
                    const isItemSelected = isSelected(emp.id);
                    return (
                        <TableRow hover key={emp._id}>
                            <TableCell> {emp.id} </TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    )
                }
            )

        })()
    }
</TableBody>
```

Comment: Bro I tried this but it doesnt work for me , i got an error on TableBody

Comment: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: { component: ElementType<any>; } & CommonProps<TableBodyTypeMap<{}, "tbody">> & Pick<any, string | number | symbol>): Element', gave the following error.
    Property 'component' is missing in type '{ children: void; }' but required in type '{ component: ElementType<any>; }'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: DefaultComponentProps<TableBodyTypeMap<{}, "tbody">>): Element', gave the following error.
    Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.

Comment: @RamAravind. From what you say, it appears that you have a missing prop `'component'` in either `<TableRow>` or `<TableCell>`. In addition, probably one of your props is returning nothing (`'void'`) instead of a component/node. For assistance, could you please edit your question by providing the implementation for `<TableRow>` , `<TableCell>` and `<TableBody>`?